# Running executable from VS2008 crashes with error "Application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)" x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

This error is present in both Debug/Release.

So the original problem was that it had 32 bit library that I did not link to 64 version of it.
(Previous version of this question)
I fixed that.

And application works on Windows Server Standard 2008R2 x64.

I tried running application on Windows Server Enterprise but got above (title) mentioned error message.

Dependency walker says "Modules with different CPU types were found" and for some reason it seems its linking incorrectly to 32 bit library, but thats something that comes from mshtml.dll (win lib) and it links to winsxs\x86.. folder to COMCTL32.dll, but that lib is in System32 folder (correct one ) so not sure why is it linking to this one

Any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

> I tried re-installing Visual C++ redistributable but no help.

Which one - the one that came with your installed and patched VC compiler, or did you download it from the net?  Did you install the 32 bit redist or the 64 bit - they are seperate installs, ie 64 bit redist doesn't include 32 bit redist files.

> Modules with different CPU types were found

yes, you have to match the CPU type, all 32 bit or all 64 bit.

Given the IESHIMS gives the impression working on a browser plugin

- If your making a Browser Helper Object (BHO - IE addon-on/extension)  then you need to register seperately 32 & 64 bit, but if your connecting to ie as an external server then you just need to make sure you have the right one to match the rest of your app.
- If your making a FF plug-in then don't forget to add the mozilla directory to the search path for depends, and when you make changes don't forget you have to reset the firefox plugin cache to try and load the plug-in again (change the folder name, start FF, then change the name back)

> %ProgramFiles%/Internet Explorer to System32.

So that would be the 64bit ie dll, to the ??/System32

I'd recommend removing any of the dlls you have added to system32, that way leads to dll hell.

Comment: BHO? 
the problem is that I am not linking to 32 bit library. If you look at link with image I posted Win stuff connects to 32 bit version incorrectly... and i agree i need to remove them from sys32 but this was added as last resort. i tried both the one that comes with vs2008 and from the msdn web site

Comment: @grobartn: The image of depends doesn't show the 'CPU' column so it's not possible to tell which items are 32 or 64.
The other thing is that depends.exe has 32 and 64 bit versions, using 32 bit depends on 64 bit exe/dll will show incorrect info.

Comment: i am using 64 bit version and the one that is 32 bit is COMCTL32.dll
It points to directory that contains it and starts with winsxs\x86... which clearly shows it is 32 bit...that is the part i dont understand because 64 bit version of COMCTL32.dll is right there in system32 and its finding the rest libs from that folder why   finding this one in entirely diff folder...and this is not the web app it has small part that deals with web service but its command line app

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

I had the same problem with Adobe Dreamweaver CS6.

**Solution:**

1. Check your software package(folder from where you installed application) it may include cracked folder or patch folder with 64 bit and 32 bit cracked/patched DLL file.

Note: If you do not have this folder then download from any dll website. (file specifically for adobe dream weaver: amtlib.dll)

2. Copy 32 bit DLL file for 32Bit version of application OR copy other one for 64 bit.(not your PC version, it will be application version).

3.Paste in the folder where you installed that application.