# How to Deploy c# project with all dependencies in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have created a small c# program in visual studio 2012, I used two external dll libraries. When I build the project for release, it creates the release file with a bunch of other files, including the external dll's I used. It works on my computer, but if I copy that whole release file to another computer it just gives me an error message and exits.
What else does the program need to run?

The error message is:

The application was unable to start correctly(0x000007b). click OK to close the application.

Comment: *What does the error message say*?

Comment: Depends. Showing the error message might be helpful.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: I have added the error message to the post

Comment: Put try-catch in the code to show exception details. I suppose, you made project with different target platform than another computer has (say .NET 4.5 instead of .NET 2.0) and the application expects to have 4.5 libraries on 2.0 platform

Comment: on which versions of windows operating systems your are running this?

Comment: I am downloading dot NET installer to see if that solves

Comment: Are you sure that your external libraries run on any PC? You may as well be missing one of their dependencies that is already installed on your PC.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207450/running-executable-from-vs2008-crashes-with-error-application-was-unable-to-sta

Comment: Thank you all, i have solved the problem, i just needed to install .net 4.5 on the client pc, will include this in my program folder.

Comment: Add this as an answer - so people don't try fixing a problem that you've already solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your error code is actually **0xC000007B** (STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT), rather than 0x0000007B (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE). The former is common when your application encounters a runtime mixup between the 32 and 64 bit versions of a DLL.

What could be happening is that your application (say it's 32 bit) has a dependency on a certain DLL, call it FOO.DLL. When run on your local machine, you are picking up the correct version of the 32 bit version of FOO.DLL on your path. But when you deploy to the other machine, you are picking up a 64 bit version from somewhere on the system path. The INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT error is thrown when the loader finds a 64 bit DLL trying to be loaded into your 32 bit app.

One way to fix this is by identifying the DLL and redistributing the correct version with your application.